# Injecting a variable into an anonymous function

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to inject a variable into an annonymous function without passing it in as a parameter, or without placing it in the global scope?  I.e. I'm looking for if one could do something similar to this:

```js
/** example 1 */
class A extends Array{
  constructor(...args: any){
    super(...args) // `super` exists here, even though it is not passed in as a parameter
  }
}

/** example 2 */
function B(){
  console.log(arguments) // `arguments` exists here, even though it is not passed in as a parameter
}
```

The following is some pseudo code of what I'd like to achieve.

```js
const fn1 = (supVal:string)=>{
  // can one inject `magicHiddenVariable` into `fn` below, without passing it in as a parameter?
  const magicHiddenVariable = supVal 
  return (fn:(...args: any)=>any)=>fn()
}

const usageExample = fn1('hello')
// `magicHiddenVariable` should be accessible here with 'hello'
usageExample(()=>console.log(magicHiddenVariable))
```

I'm not asking for the following solution:

```js
let  magicHiddenVariable3:string 
// `magicHiddenVariable3` is now available to all functions within its closure.
// however this is not the solution
// I'm after, as it's not limited to the scope of fn2
const fn2 = (supVal:string)=>{
  magicHiddenVariable3 = supVal 
  return (fn:(...args: any)=>any)=>fn()
}
const usageExample2 = fn2('hello')
usageExample(()=>console.log(magicHiddenVariable3))
```

[code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=31&ssc=52&pln=24&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZmAjDAvDAFBArgBwGoCGANgFzQBOAlmAOYCUKAfAN4CwAUDDAPTczAEwMcAFMY1AFYjgsAAYBbAjUrAAEpQAmGkWEJUCAIyIjZ4sFBAxZCUwZFEQAdwA0MR5SgALEFlg4CEBDUNOKw1DABETD+5ATyIlAi5AD8HFygkLCKymqa2roE+kZiaNj4xDBpMOQJWORC6Agk6AB0bYU0ECQRYACeDIyC-UwI6HQcAL4cHBnQMFgQSiIAogAecTjGqPBI6ADknvYOe+PsC0trG8boY0yzIMYtDjTo2SrqWjp6lIbGdHQ8PgKJTvPJfQo-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-iAA)

Comment: Is this [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? The example use case does not make much sense. At best, it seems you want to use a global.

Comment: @VLAZ - `super` and `arguments` are not globals, but specific to the particular function they are being used in.  I'm trying to emulate that functionality.

Comment: I mean, you can't. `super` and `arguments` are baked into the language. You cannot just add new language keywords. Hence the question of *what you're actually trying to do*?

Comment: @VLAZ - I'm creating a function that is similar to class inheritance and therefore I'm looking to recreate the `super` functionality myself.  One solution is to pass it into the constructor, however, I prefer the way it's done in class - i.e. it just exists.  I suspect you are right - it cannot be done, but I thought I would ask anyway - perhaps someone knows some magic I don't know.  It's done in constructor - so it is at least theoretically possible.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is use a modular function with a ref returned.

```js
function useIt(supVal) {
   const magic = {value:supVal}
   const fn1 = (...args:any)=>{
     magic.value = args
   }
   return {fn1,  magic}
}


const {fn1, magic} = useIt('bar')
fn1('aVal')
console.log(magic.value)
fn1('aVal2')
console.log(magic.value)

fn1(()=>console.log(magic.value))
```

You could also put the value in the function itself.

```js
function useIt(supVal) {
   const fn1 = (...args:any)=>{
     const fn1.magic = args
   }
   return fn1
}
const fn1 = useIt('bar')
fn1('aVal')
console.log(fn1.magic)
fn1('aVal2')
console.log(fn1.magic)

fn1(()=>console.log(fn1.magic))
```

Comment: in this solution, you are passing `magicHiddenVariable` as a parameter and that's specifically what I don't want to do.  `super` and `arguments` are not globals, nor are they passed in as parameters, however, they exist in particular functions and are unique to those functions.

Comment: I inverted solution to be closer to your request, but same concept.  It is  as close as i see you getting.